# Character comparison in C?

Tags: c, comparison, character

When I pass in one of the characters I specified, it returns `2` as if it was an incorrect character? Am I comparing these incorrectly?

```
int valid_character(char character) {
    if (character == '*' || character == '%' || character == '#') {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**edit:**

The problem is where I am calling the function:

```
if (selection == 1) {
    printf("Enter character, width and length: ");
    scanf("%c %d %d", &c, &width, &length);
    putchar(c);
    int response = valid_character(c);
    if (response == 1) {
        draw_rectangle(width, length, c);
    } else {
        printf("%d", response);
        printf("Invalid data provided.");
    }
}
```

When I call `putchar(c);` it prints out `1` even though I am passing in `%`
Why is this?

Comment: Why would it return 2?

Comment: There might be something weird in your call to valid_character... post that too? this works fine for me...

Comment: Are you certain you're passing one of those characters?  Try calling it directly, and pass it `'*'`, then print the return value.  It should be `1`.

Comment: Are you declaring `c` as `char`?

Comment: this is at the top of my main method:

Comment: int main () {
  int selection = 1;
  char c = '%';

Comment: I fixed it, I simply had to add " %c%d%d" in my scanf statement to tell it to skip any white space rather than the slightly different "%c%d%d"

Comment: @Jenny: You did not post the whole function! you probably had another `scanf` before the code fragment that left a pending `\n` in the input stream

Comment: There's a reason we request people to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) — it helps avoid these problems.  The `scanf()` family of functions are fiendishly hard to use reliably.  Take a look at how many beginners on SO end up asking questions about them.  It's a lot!  And `%c` causes endless trouble because it doesn't skip white space, unlike almost all the other conversions (`%[…]` scansets and `%n` being the other two that don't skip white space).

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the whole function! you probably had another `scanf` before the code fragment that left a pending `\n` in the input stream.

As you found out yourself, you can skip this `\n` and any other white space by reading the character with:

```
scanf(" %c%d%d", &c, &width, &length);
```